# group_by/aggregate/mutate? New variable based on ID and another variable

Tags: r, group-by, aggregate, dplyr

Happy Eastern.

I have a question. I have the following dataset

```
df<-data.frame(ID=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),
               Obs=c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4),
               other=c(12,12,24,24,13,13,13,16,11,11,11,11))

   ID Obs other
1   1   1    12
2   1   2    12
3   1   3    24
4   1   4    24
5   2   1    13
6   2   2    13
7   2   3    13
8   2   4    16
9   3   1    11
10  3   2    11
11  3   3    11
12  3   4    11
```

I would like to get a new variable that is based on ID and other. It should get the same value for each value of other and this should be done WITHIN each ID.

See here

```
newdf<-data.frame(ID=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),
                  Obs=c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4),
                  other=c(12,12,24,24,13,13,13,16,11,11,11,11),
                  Day=c(1,1,2,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1))

   ID Obs other Day
1   1   1    12   1
2   1   2    12   1
3   1   3    24   2
4   1   4    24   2
5   2   1    13   1
6   2   2    13   1
7   2   3    13   1
8   2   4    16   2
9   3   1    11   1
10  3   2    11   1
11  3   3    11   1
12  3   4    11   1
```

I have tried this, but I was obviously not successful.

```
1. df$Day %>%
  group_by(ID,other) 

Error in UseMethod("group_by") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_by' applied to an object of class "NULL"
```

I cannot seem to figure it out. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Greetings, Dominique

Answer (score 0):

I just found it out.

Jesus Christ...

```
d2<-df %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(ID) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(obs=dense_rank(other))
```

gives

```
      ID   Obs other   obs
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
 1     1     1    12     1
 2     1     2    12     1
 3     1     3    24     2
 4     1     4    24     2
 5     2     1    13     1
 6     2     2    13     1
 7     2     3    13     1
 8     2     4    16     2
 9     3     1    11     1
10     3     2    11     1
11     3     3    11     1
12     3     4    11     1
```